# Give custom border to TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-drawable

How can I give the custom border to TextView where:
1) left and right border is 2 dp and with the different color with little opacity
2) top and bottom border is 1 dp
3) The text of TextView should be visible. right now What I have created is not showing the text of textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FF000000" />
        <solid android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Can you show required background image also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use alpha color according to your recruitment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#080808" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#76d63f" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d63f60" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#3fa9d6" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Its giving me 2dp border as top,I changed it to 1 but still it shows same 2dp.

Comment: you need to change both for 3rd and 4th item in list

Comment: Thanks, But when I add corner radius it makes it round from inner side whereas corner from outside remains sharp. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#76d273" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#76d63f" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d63f60" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

add this code in your drawable(test_drawable) file and set to textview

```
android:background="@drawable/test_drawable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my code I have integrated the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    //for top and bottom borders
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#fff70b" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    //for left and right border
    <item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#e90c0c" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please note that opacity should be defined when creating your color only. While writing your color in colors.xml, you can change opacity like shown in below screenshot. Either change the 255 to your chosen opacity or use the bottom bar.

[image]

Also, you need to define the **solid** tag for each border and apply transparent color in order to make your TextView visible.
After applying the code in drawable, you will be able to see some preview like this :

[image]

Good Luck..!!